# How to select a hashed password from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I'm trying to make a register/login code for my personal website.
I had no troubles making the registration form but I'm having some difficulties with the login.
Here's a part of my code:

```
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT password FROM members where username = ? ");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $username);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Now to my understanding i need to fetch the first row from my table convert it to a string and then using `password_verify` to compare that string to whatever the users inputs in the form i created. The problem i have is that it fetches an array and can't really use `password_verify` to compare a string to an array.
Am I doing something wrong? how should I do this?
tl; dr How do I actually select a hashed password from DB, convert it to a string and then compare that string with the password my user will input.
Thanks.

Comment: the answers are all in the manuals for this; have you not consulted them? edit: this being a question that needs a response of "yes" or "no". Did you notice the question mark?

Comment: I am sorry if this has been asked before but i searched and didnt really find my answer, also been looking up php manual for almost two hours. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: [`password_verify()`  The manual... Read it!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: consult the duplicate it was closed with and make sure the password column is min. 60 length. The manual says that 255 is a good bet.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 1):

This library works on
  PHP 5.5+: use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$users = $result->fetchAll();
if (isset($users[0]) {
  if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $users[0]->password) {
    // valid login
  } else {
    // invalid password
  }
} else {
  // invalid username
}
```